# how to access 2d array values?

Tags: php, arrays

do you have any idea why the "echo" in the following loop doesn't work?

```
while( $nl = mysql_fetch_array($Lresult) )
{
    $clkword[$i] = $nl['Word'];
    $relatedlinks[$i] = array(
        $i => array(
            "CWord" => $nl['Word'],
            "RLinks" => $nl['Link_Add']
        )
    );
    echo $relatedlinks[$i]['CWord'];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the way you've set it up, `$relatedlinks[$i]` is an array containing (at the key `$i`) an array containing keys `"CWord"` and `"RLinks"`. In other words, you have an array inside an array inside an array, whereas what you wanted was an array inside an array. Change the line

```
$relatedlinks[$i]=array($i => array("CWord" => $nl['Word'],
                                    "RLinks" => $nl['Link_Add']));
```

to read

```
$relatedlinks[$i] = array( "CWord"  => $nl['Word'],
                           "RLinks" => $nl['Link_Add']
                           );
```